# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Tags: javascript

Here's what I'm trying to achiev: I have a center circle div, that contains 5 other divs. When I rotate a device on gamma axis, I want the circle div to rotate accordingly to the gamma degree, but the 5 inner divs to rotate in counter direction (sort of create an illusion that the inner divs are not actually spinning, sort of a ferris wheel effect). I wrote this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",onload); 

function onload(){

    if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
        console.log("DeviceOrientation is supported");
        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData){
            var tiltLR = eventData.gamma;
            deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR);
        }, false);
    } else {
        console.log("DeviceOrientation NOT supported");
    }
}

var lastTilt = 0;

function deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR) {
    var circle = document.getElementById('center-circle');
    var str = window.getComputedStyle(circle, null);
    var trans = str.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform");
    var tr_values = trans.split('(')[1],
        tr_values = tr_values.split(')')[0],
        tr_values = tr_values.split(',');
    circle.style.webkitTransform = "translate("+tr_values[4]+"px, "+tr_values[5]+"px) rotate("+ tiltLR +"deg)"


    var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('icon-circle');
    tiltLR = Math.abs(tiltLR);
    for (var i = 0; i <= icons.length; i++){
        var el = icons[i];
        var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
        var tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform");
        var values = tr.split('(')[1],
            values = values.split(')')[0],
            values = values.split(',');
        if (tiltLR > lastTilt) {
            icons[i].style.webkitTransform = "translate("+values[4]+"px, "+values[5]+"px) rotate(-"+ tiltLR +"deg)";
        } else {
            icons[i].style.webkitTransform = "translate("+values[4]+"px, "+values[5]+"px) rotate("+ tiltLR +"deg)";
        }
        console.log("el"+i+": "+tr+" | vals: "+values);
    }

    lastTilt = tiltLR;
}
```

The problem is inside the `for` loop - when the code gets to this line `var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);` I'm getting these error messages: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'`. I tried to change the `el` var to `icons[i].id`, but it didn't help.

Any ideas why it;s happening and how to fix it?

Comment: When you loop until `i <= icons.length` you're overshooting the array by one.

Comment: Could you give us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Juhana Thank you! Can't believe I missed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Juhana mentioned in comments, your last loop will fail because there is no element `var el = icons[i]; // where i=icons.length`

hence change your loop to

```
for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++){//change <= to <
```

and it should work.